# Land on specific URL java servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a servlet and a jsp running on a Tomcat server. Whenever navigate to the following URL it works fine but displays only the static content on the JSP

```
http://localhost:8080/demo/result
```

However in my servlet I'm getting a parameter like below

```
String resultParam = request.getParameter("type");
```

I get the resultParam and pass it on to my java class to a database query.
So every time I have to use the following URL to see the actual content on the page

```
http://localhost:8080/demo/result?type=today
```

Actual users of my webpage don't know about this. They are expecting to land in the above URL when they just navigate to http://localhost:8080/demo/result

My web.xml looks like

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>result</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.result.servlet.ResultServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>result</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/result</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `resultParam`.
If it's `null` you have 2 options:

1. Send a http redirect to ..?type=today
2. set `resultParam = today` and continue as always

Comment: I think there is a better way to do that through web.xml or getRequestDispatcher method. I'm looking for that method.

Comment: The second option is perfectly fine. It works like a default. +1

Comment: @Verim : Do I have to redirect like this?

   if(resultParam == null) {
    resultParam = "today";
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/result.jsp?type=today").forward(request, response);
   }
   else {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/result.jsp").forward(request, response);
   }